# Finding out pixel coordinates of the block of text in an image

Tags: javascript, image

I have a .png image. The images contains various text blocks. I would like to find the position of each of these text blocks in the image. These blocks are rectangular.

Since the blocks are rectangular I would require the pixel values of the top left corner and then the length and breadth of the rectangle.

Can I use any software to do this? Or some simple way of doing it?

The main purpose of this is to identify the div of that size in javascript and then make it clickable.

Example of the image could be https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bup6lvwqs30ls4e/AACEQpGRhuKLyPa61fCzjV0sa?lst=#lh:null-12.png and I would like to find the pixel locations of say Nutrition list and ingredients list.

Comment: Please show an example of that image.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is a png image and nothing else, and you want to infer text position from it, it is a extremely difficult Computer Vision problem and there is no simple JavaScript library you can leverage. If you can setup some sort of service to process this image, i.e. upload this image to a server, calculate the bounding boxes inside these images, then you have a few choices:

- I don't care about the accuracy, and I just want my stuff to work: http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/
- I want to use the state of the art: start reading from http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dwu4/ICDAR2011.pdf , and use Google to find related stuff

Comment: I need not do it dynamically. If I can figure out for the shared image then I can even hard code those values and should be fine with me for now.

Comment: I am not sure about the comment 'I need to do it dynamically'. What is stopping you from uploading the image to the server -> figure out the bounding box -> render the boxes? If you try to implement either tesseract's algorithm or some other more sophisticated CV algorithm in JavaScript, most likely it would be much slower than the server side option unless you spend a large amount of time optimizing it.